# Make cinematic-like intro on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want to display a few words – like the example `<h1>` elements below – on scroll before the actual site appears.

```
<div id="main">
  <h1 id="i_1">Text 1</h1>
  <h1 id="i_2" class="hide">Text 2</h1>
  <h1 id="i_3" class="hide">Text 3</h1>
  <h1 id="i_4" class="hide">Logo</h1>
</div>
```

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on8wv8zx/1/) so you can see what I am talking about. The main part of my JS is using the `$(window).scroll()` to change which `<h1>` is displayed on screen.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 200) {
        i_1.removeClass('hide').addClass("show");
    }
    if (scroll > 400) {
        i_1.removeClass('show').addClass("hide");
    }
    …
```

First, I am not sure if there's a better way to do what I already did.
Second, I want the "Logo" at the end to move to the top on scroll – it should 'transform' into the header.

All I could find was related to fixed headers, or slider-like intros with a fullscreen background, which isn't at all what i want.

It would be nice if I could at least get a direction on what I need to look for to achieve what I want. I would prefer a CSS-only solution, but anything else is fine as well.

Comment: |Not for nothing, and not really an answer, but impress.js is quite interesting, you might find some nice inspiration // use from it! https://github.com/impress/impress.js

Comment: Very interesting, i will sure have a closer look on this too. It really is as you say a quite nice inspiration, also on what really is possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to your other JS, operating based on scroll height, you can do the following:

```
    if (scroll > 1600) {
        $('#main').addClass("header");
    }
    if (scroll < 1600) {
        $('#main').removeClass("header");
    }
```

And then in CSS you just need to manipulate `#main.header` to change the way you want it by setting new values for `top` and `transform` and using the [CSS `transition` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to make these change gradually over a given amount of time.

```
#main {
    …
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: top 1s linear, transform 1s linear;
}

#main.header {
  top: 0%;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

You can also do similar to `h1`, say, for instance, changing its `font-size` gradually.

```
#main.header h1 {
  font-size: 58pt;  
}
h1 {
  transition: font-size 1s linear;
}
```

I've updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on8wv8zx/3/) to show it in action.

Comment: So simple... Thank you very much :)